# V-Calendar works only according to date, doesn't work according to given times. How to work with times?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vcalendar

I am using the v-calendar component. And I want to display a dot on the calendar according to my event date. I work with milliseconds on the backend side. So I give the event datetimes as milliseconds to the calendar.

Here are my codes;

```
import VCalendar from 'v-calendar/lib/components/calendar.umd';

<VCalendar
 :locale="locale"
 :attributes="attributes"
 :is-expanded="true"
 @dayclick="onDayClick"
 :model-config="modelConfig"
 @update:to-page="navigation"
 />

  data () {
    return {
      locale: {
        id: 'tr',
        masks: { weekdays: 'WWW' },
      },
      modelConfig: {
        type: 'number',
      },
      attributes: [
        {
          dot: 'red',
          dates: [
            {
              start: 1648364400000, // 2022-03-27 10:00:00 in my timezone(tr)
              end: 1648501200000, // 2022-03-29 00:00:00 in my timezone(tr)
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    };   },
```

In this scenario, I expect the end date should be excluded and the dot should not be shown on 29 March because I give the time as 00:00:00. The dots only should be shown on 27 March and 28 March. But it doesn't work like this. What should I do for the calendar works with times?

[image]

Here is code sandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-breeze-ibf6im?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: I ran your code, and it's working as the result you want to achieve : https://i.imgur.com/8kc8Akk.png 
Can you perhaps update your package. btw I'm using vue3

Comment: I am using vue2 and v-calendar version is "v-calendar": ".^2.4.1" but it still doesn't work. Here is codesandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-breeze-ibf6im?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: The codesandbox is showing the correct dots, I even downloaded vue2 with vcal ^2.4.1 and run it. It's still working for me. I also changed my windows country and language to Turkish, and still working for me. Can you perhaps try to run this on another device ?

Comment: I tried on the other devices and the other timezones but it still doesn't work. Did you try to change your timezone to Istanbul - Turkey? I guess to change country and language is not enough to change timezone. Did you try with a different end date which has the time as 00:00:00 according to your timezone?